# o-llvm (based on llvm3.4) emit obfuscated code

Tags: c, obfuscation, llvm-clang

I'm learning how to use [o-llvm](https://github.com/obfuscator-llvm/obfuscator/wiki) based on llvm 3.4.

I have a really simple c file, named "Example.c" that I'm obfuscating and compiling.

```
clang -mllvm -sub Example.c
```

Is there a way to emit the obfuscated code as a .c file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LLVM Obfuscation happens after the C code has been transformed to LLVM IR. There is not really a good way to convert IR directly back into C code either. You can have o-llvm output the obfuscated code as IR though by using the command line arguments

```
-S -emit-llvm
```

Comment: What i was planning to do is generating a CFG dump of the obfuscated code, that's why i wanted the source...
My plan was: Obfuscate Example.c --> generate ObfuscatedExample.c --> Generate CFG dump of ObfuscatedExample.c

is this possible even with the IR?